# Iterating through DataContract class

Tags: c#, list, loops, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I have a class that returns a `Response2` which includes only two definitions I care about:

```
Response3.Id
Response3.Name
```

But, this data is returned as a list, b/c my class definition looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Response2
{
    [DataMember(Name = "done")]
    public bool done;
    [DataMember(Name = "records")]
    public List<Response3> r3entry;
}

[DataContract]
public class Response3
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Id")]
    public string strId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string strName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a List of strings to iterate through, but when I try to do the following:

```
Response2 propResponse2 = MakeRequest2(propertyRequest2, sfToken);

foreach (string strId in propResponse2)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(strId.Name)
}
```

I get an error stating:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Response2' because 'Response2' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I assume that means I need to add something to the DataContract in the class, but I'm not sure where to do this so I can properly iterate.

Any help?

Comment: You must be coming from a `JavaScript` world.  --- I assume `propResponse2` is of type `Response2`? If so, then I assume you're trying to iterate over the data members of the class? `foreach` will not do that. And there is no such beast. I assume you're trying to serialize the class. For that, use `DataContractSerializer` or `NetDataContractSerializer`

Comment: How is `propResponse2` defined?

Comment: @UweKeim, from the error message it's obvious it's declared as `Response2`

Comment: @UweKeim - i updated the question with the definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (var resp3 in propResponse2.r3entry)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(resp3.strName)
}
```

Comment: this worked, but needs to be changed to `resp3.strName`

Answer (score 1):

To do what you're wanting (if that is indeed what you want) you need to use `reflection`

```
        foreach (var field in propResponse2.GetType().GetFields())
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(field.GetValue(propResponse2).ToString());
        }
```

if on the other hand you're wanting to get all the [DataContract] properties from all the fields, then:

```
foreach (DataContract dc in propResponse2.GetType()
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataContract), false).Length > 0)
            .SelectMany(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<DataContract>()).ToArray())
{
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(dc.Name);

}
```

Comment: so what's the downside of iterating through this list? i'm not sure i understand why `reflection` is bad and getting all the properties from all the fields is good? the issue is not that i want only "some" of the properties, but rather that this is defined as a list, so there are many "sets" of these properties in the list and i want to iterate through those individual items.

Comment: @gotmike: I didn't say `reflection` is bad. I'm just not sure what you're wanting. Are you wanting the values of the fields of `propResponse2` or are you wanting the `DataContract.Name` value?  Reflection is slower than compile-time access for sure, but reflection has been optimized in C#. The "issue" is that if this is code that will be executed a lot then reflection is a performance issue.